# Looking for a function that can retrieve the title of a file in *right-click file*>properties>details>title

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to find an a function that can find the title. I have tried os.stat(file) but it only returns the details on the general tab, and I can't find any other attribute in os.stat that can retrieve the stuff on details. For example my code:

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\\PythonScripts')
statinfo = os.stat('01 of CDImage01.mp3')
print(statinfo)
```

I am planning to make a program that can swap the title and the file name.

Comment: The information you're looking for is known as "ID3" in MP3 files.  Once you know that, it is easier to search for solutions.

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I was looking for.